# PHPmailer and pdf attachment

Tags: php, email, pdf, attachment, phpmailer

I'm trying to send an email with a PDF attachment using the phpmailer class.

I used this code:

Within `mailTo` function:

```
$mail->AddAttachment($pdffile);
```

where `$pdffile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/facturen/test.pdf"`

Sending the mail results in an email without attachment but with:

```
--b1_3768f40f33d9a5dec555d03a15af14f9
Content-Type: text/html; charset = "iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

at the top of my email and on the bottom of my email:

```
--b1_3768f40f33d9a5dec555d03a15af14f9 
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="test.pdf" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.pdf" 

JVBERi0xLjQKJcfsj6IKMTEgMCBvYmoKPDwvTGVuZ3RoIDEyIDAgUi9GaWx0ZXIgL0ZsYXRlRGVj
b2RlPj4Kc3RyZWFtCnic7VtZs9zEFa5A2CYpQyALSUiiNyQqI3pfeGOrOECgMJc8BPJg38Xbta8x
NqbyL/Jn85yvF6mPpNbMXMoPVCrlskvT6j59+izfWdT+pmG9UA0Lf4aH43ubt69x2dz8dsOb8Ofh
zY2zrGfeNU7yXmvf3Ns4wXrDxDhiHes50431vGdGlt8K741pjjfDiMEMbZuBgNHhp2qGLYbfxxvP 
fa+9Gke8CTOG9flXoT8MZAaG1QOD8yMcb87e2sieCwXST3DUj/D3Tj7ytb/8bx751uaLzTcNV1r3 
0kVtcy5Vr3ijmeqNwFzfc+51tgLVfHCx+XwT7SMIRbMgsUAZkzkPlFygBCq2V83D00jfOZAUJtE3 
eHamwSoBJhvJlOidzfR1or97iXAWm/i8xBy0xHLZDytsfYXoPV2hNes9z0tcWgKxKq5NMA8RVJCn 
QVzO6UjKaJxb6XTyJCa4yzcb1XNjjI
```

and so on...

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 12):

Try this, it work for me ...

```
   $mail->AddAttachment('path_to_pdf', $name = 'Name_for_pdf',  $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/pdf');
```

In your case

```
    $mail->AddAttachment($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/facturen/test.pdf', $name = 'test',  $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/pdf');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use three more parameters, all of which are optional:

```
AddAttachment($path,$name,$encoding,$type);
```

also follow this answer: [Send File Attachment from Form Using phpMailer and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764156/send-file-attachment-from-form-using-phpmailer-and-php)

There is an additional way to add an attachment. If you want to make a HTML e-mail with images incorporated into the desk, it's necessary to attach the image and then link the `<img src="cid:CID" />` tag to it. For example, if you add an image as inline attachment with the CID my-photo, you would access it within the HTML e-mail with `<img src="cid:my-photo" alt="my-photo" />`.

In detail, here is the function to add an inline attachment:

```
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage(filename, cid, name);
```

By using this function with this example's value above, results in this code:

```
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('my-photo.jpg', 'my-photo', 'my-photo.jpg ');
```

Comment: Thank you, but i'm trying to attach a PDF. I know about the $name,$encoding,$type parameters, but how do they help me in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:
[Add attachment through PHPMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776126/add-attachment-through-phpmailer)
It seems totatly unrelated, but helped me too. THere must be problem with setting the Email body