# How to send fillable pdf (filled with pdftk) via PHPMailer?

Tags: php, pdf, phpmailer, pdftk

I have a form on a website that customers fill. When user filles the form and clicks submit data is sent to a pdf(invoice) I've already created and certain spots in pdf are filled with that data. I did this using PDFTK library:

```
public function generate($data)
    {
        $filename =  date("d-m-Y-His") . ".pdf";

        $pdf = new Pdf('./form.pdf');
        $pdf->fillForm($data)
        ->flatten()
        ->saveAs('./completed/' . $filename);

        $path = './completed/' .$filename;

        return $path;
    }
```

The problem is, i dont know how to send this filled pdf via PHPMailer library, as pdf is recquired to be a string in order to work with phpmailer.

```
$pdf = new GeneratePDF;
$response = $pdf->generate($data);

$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->SetFrom('you@example.com', 'Your Name'); 
$email->Subject   = 'Test';
$email->Body      = 'Test';
$email->AddAddress( 'mail exmp' );


$email->AddAttachment( $response , 'NameOfFile.pdf' );

$email->Send();
```

And how to actually save file in cpanel server, as when i do this it doesnt work on a server.

Comment: are you sure the path is ok, './completed/' . $filename and 'NameOfFile.pdf'

check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31872220/477902

Comment: @flakerimi yeah, when I work on local xampp server, pdf is filled correctly and is saved. The PHPMailer part is just an example where i want to integrate pdf somehow

Comment: what does $response return?

Comment: i mate it return pdfs path now, but it still is not working on a live server

Comment: you should check server php version and php extensions and debug more

Answer (score 0):

> pdf is recquired to be a string in order to work with phpmailer

This is not true. `addAttachment()` requires that you pass in *a path* to a local file on disk, so you could do:

```
$email->addAttachment(generate(), 'NameOfFile.pdf');
```

You *can* pass in a binary string using `addStringAttachment()`, but that's not what you're asking for here.

Comment: I edited my questions code, can you see it now. Do you think it will work like that on server? As i need to do all that on server, not with local file

Comment: Your revised code won’t help. You are still trying to pass the generated PDF as a path when it doesn’t have one.

Comment: i made it return a path now, but it still not working on a live server

Comment: You need to define "not working". We have no information to work with here. Check the path that it generates, make sure that it points at a real file, make sure that it contains valid PDF data, and do all that *before* you attempt to send it via email. Debug one thing at a time.

Comment: Mail sending works fine. All paths are good, i checked them, and i can reach form.pdf properly, the only problem is fillpdf(+flatten, +saveas) part, it does not generate pdf on a server as it did on my local pc. As if the whole pdftk library is not working unlike PHPmailer library which works fine

Comment: Ok, so it looks like you need to check ownership and permissions of where you’re trying to save it, or switch to generating an in-memory string instead.