# PHP mailer attachment email not working

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am working with phpmailer and trying to send an email with attachment but email is not working (no email sending) as well as attachment.

```
require_once 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
if (isset($_REQUEST['FindDealer'])) {
    $mail->AddAddress('whoto@otherdomain.com', 'John Doe');
    $mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
    $mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
    $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), advanced';
    $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message,
    $mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents('contents . html'));
    $email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'pdf . pdf);
    return $email->Send();
    exit;
}
```

Please guide me about this ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776126/add-attachment-through-phpmailer

Comment: Look at the color coding, can you see the difference? You are missing a  `';`at your `$mail->AltBody =` line

Comment: @Epodax thx dear ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you used every line the variable `$mail` except on these lines:

```
$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'pdf . pdf);
return $email->Send();
```

change them to the following and it should working:

```
$mail->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'pdf . pdf);
return $mail->Send();
```

EDIT: And fix the errors (see on the syntax highlighting):

```
require_once 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
if (isset($_REQUEST['FindDealer'])) {
    $mail->AddAddress('whoto@otherdomain.com', 'John Doe');
    $mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
    $mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
    $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), advanced';
    $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, ';
    $mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents('contents . html'));
    $mail->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'pdf . pdf');
    return $mail->Send();
    exit;
}
```